# Running create-react-app on web server shows blank page

Tags: node.js, reactjs

So kind of a newb question here. I am new to React. I can run create-react-app on my pc and go to localhost:3000 and I see the starter page just fine. However when I run the same command on my DigitalOcean CentOS droplet, and then proceed to the URL, the title shows but the viewport is just a blank white screen. I am using Nginx and Phusion Passenger to host multiple websites. Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: heck for errors in your web browsers Network Tab and Javascript Console. This will tell you if there were any JS errors, or if any resources failed to load. I assume resource are trying to load from the wrong source.

Comment: Just created a brand new react app. Went to the URL. The title shows "React App" and inspect element shows the index.html file in my public directory. However the react landing page still doesn't show. It's just a blank white page. The only error showing in network/console is 400 bad request for the /%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico

Comment: Did you ever solve this error?